# Specifiy field_type in Drupal Node Add public form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using this:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91186/how-do-i-embed-a-node-creation-form-inside-a-view (top rated answer) to implement a node add form for front-end users in an iframe. Now everything works perfect with:

```
<?php 
   module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
   $node_form = node_add('post');
   print drupal_render($node_form);
?>
```

The problem is, I want to prefix an option.
It works perfect with /?q=node/add/post?field_type=3 but then I don't have the form in my iframe. How can I put the "field_type=3" inside the "node_form" value?

Answer (score 0):

try `HOOK_FORM_ALTER` to add  "field_type=3" inside the "node_form"

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Comment: Is it not possible inside there? I'm placing this PHP code in three different view headers and each has a different field type. How do I handle it most effective?

Comment: not sure..I think you can create function and call it for all forms with required parameters